# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) Relm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cocoapods

I am using a Realm database in my iOS project. My build is always successful but when app runs in the simulator, it generates the above exception at initialization of the Realm object.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced that error and I did following steps
1)Just rebuild the project
2)Restart the xcode
3)changed my simulator 
 app started working correctly.